# TextField first cell result shows in other cells in Tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I am developing an IOS App. The problem is that using text field in table view. Value entered in textfield first cell of tableviewCell and the result shows in the second or third cell. Sometimes, when the tableview has only one row the result shows properly. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

   return _fetchedobj.count;
}

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
   }
   data = [_fetchedobj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   _quantity = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f,28.0f,50.0f , 30.0f)];
   [_quantity setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
   [_quantity setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
   _quantity.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   [_quantity setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
   [_quantity addTarget:self action:@selector(changedvalue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEditingEvents];
   NSString *q_value = [data valueForKey:@"quantity"];
   NSInteger q_value1 = [q_value integerValue];
   [_quantity setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)q_value1]];
   [cell addSubview:_quantity];
```

Change Value Method

```
- (void) changedvalue: (UITextField *)textfield
{

    NSString *text = [textfield text];
    NSInteger text1 = [text integerValue];

    NSString *changevalue =  [dict objectForKey:@"_max_purchases_per_user"];
    NSInteger valueChange =  [changevalue integerValue];
    NSString *userPurchase = [dict objectForKey:@"_max_purchases"];
    NSInteger itemPurchase = [userPurchase integerValue];

    NSString *amount =  [data valueForKey:@"amount"];
    NSInteger amount1 = [amount integerValue];

    NSInteger minValue=MIN(valueChange, itemPurchase);
    if (text1 > minValue) {
        [_quantity setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)minValue]];
        [_total1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",minValue * amount1]];
    }else{
   [_total1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",text1 * amount1]];
    }
  integerValue] * [aNum integerValue])]];
}
```

Comment: Could you post the changedValue: method?

Comment: you not set directly text in quantity textfield [_quantity setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)minValue]];

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the concept of reuse of cells. There are a few things that you could do to fix this.

First of all is your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Each time the method is called, you place a new UITextField even when one may already be present. Also, `_quantity` seems to be an instance variable for the viewController which is not a good practice.

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

   return _fetchedobj.count;
}

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

   UITextField *quantity;

   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

      //This is the only place a new UITextField is needed.


       quantity = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f,28.0f,50.0f , 30.0f)];
       [quantity setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
       [quantity setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
       quantity.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       [quantity setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
       [quantity addTarget:self action:@selector(changedvalue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEditingEvents];
       [quantity setTag: 1];
       [cell addSubview:quantity];

   }
   else
   {
       quantity = [cell viewWithTag: 1];
   }

   data = [_fetchedobj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSString *q_value = [data valueForKey:@"quantity"];
   NSInteger q_value1 = [q_value integerValue];
   [quantity setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)q_value1]];
}
```

Secondly, in the `changedValue:` method, you are not storing the updated values anywhere to be updated in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. Also, you need a way to track which cell the textField belongs to.

```
- (void) changedvalue: (UITextField *)textfield
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell: textfield.superview ];    

    NSString *text = [textfield text];
    NSInteger text1 = [text integerValue];

    NSString *changevalue =  [dict objectForKey:@"_max_purchases_per_user"];
    NSInteger valueChange =  [changevalue integerValue];
    NSString *userPurchase = [dict objectForKey:@"_max_purchases"];
    NSInteger itemPurchase = [userPurchase integerValue];

    NSString *amount =  [data valueForKey:@"amount"];
    NSInteger amount1 = [amount integerValue];

    NSInteger minValue=MIN(valueChange, itemPurchase);
    if (text1 > minValue) {
        [textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)minValue]];
        [_total1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",minValue * amount1]];
    }else{
        [_total1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",text1 * amount1]];
    }

  // integerValue] * [aNum integerValue])]]; This line is incomplete

   //Update the new value in the array.
   NSMutableArray *mData = [data mutableCopy];
   NSMutableDictionary *mdic = [data objectAtIndex: indexPath.row].mutableCopy;
   [mDic setObject:textField.text];
   [mData replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:mDic];
   data = mData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is never recommended that you add a subview directly to a cell. If you want something customzied create a subclass of UITableViewCell and then add your UITextField as a subview to the cell's contentView and not to the view directly.

Suppose your custom cell is MyCustomCell which contains textField.

Then your cellForRowAtIndexPath: should look like -

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
    MyCustomCell *cell = [myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    // All the rendering of quantity should be done in MyCustomCell and quantity should be added as subview to its contentView. And you should also implement prepareForReuse method in your custom cell.

    data = [_fetchedobj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *q_value = [data valueForKey:@"quantity"];
    NSInteger q_value1 = [q_value integerValue];
    // here you should just assign the data to the cell and your view controller should know nothing about the rendering of cell.
    cell.quantity.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)q_value1];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should set the contents of your table view cell in [`tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/%23//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:) method instead of the cellForRowAtIndexPath because Cocoa will try to use the last created cell (that may be cached) for the current cell.